# Copying all attribute data within table and pasting into same table to create duplicates?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, paste

I have a spatial layer with an attribute table containing 55 rows.

How do I copy all attribute data within this table and paste it into the same table to create duplicates?

I have editor turned on and I can select the attribute table and click copy but I don't know how to paste into new rows in the same table.

Comment: Do you want to copy all the Spatial data too?

Comment: Yes. Selecting all attributes and using edit > paste > target layer worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the rows you wish to copy, press and hold the CTRL key and press the C key, then press the V key while still holding CTRL.

Alternatively, you can use the Edit menu at the top of ArcMap: Select the rows, click Edit -> Copy, then click Edit -> Paste.

Either action should bring up a dialog box asking you which layer you would like to paste the features into, where you select the same layer they came from.